# Lua reading in a file

Tags: syntax, input, io, lua

So I'm trying to make my first lua program and I can't figure out why when I  read in a file it returns that the file doesn't exist or isn't in the directory...here's my code.

```
io.input("myfile.txt")
word = io.read("*line")
print (word)
```

myfile.txt is in the same directory as the project....what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: "myfile.txt is in the same directory as the project" What project? As far as I know, Lua doesn't have projects.

Comment: the file needs to exist in the same directory as the interpreter executing the lua script if you do not qualify the path.

Comment: How are you running it? myfile.txt needs to be in the *working directory* that you run the script from; depending on how you're invoking it, this may not be the same thing as the directory your script file is in!

Answer (score 1):

I can't duplicate this problem:

```
: nr@homedog 10317 ; echo foo > myfile.txt 
: nr@homedog 10318 ; lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> io.input("myfile.txt")
> word = io.read("*line")
> print (word)
foo
>
```